# Integrate HTML landing page to Hybris or redirect URL to another server

Tags: java, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a client with a website online.xxxxx.com build with Hybris/java hosted in a Tomcat server and I need to add well-designed landing pages with information about Adwords campaign, the original developers (multinational) says "it's impossible'.

The website is done with Hybris/java and hosted in Tomcat server, we only can access to the domain. I have thought in a couple of solutions:

- Have URL like https://online.xxxxxx.com/landings/ in another server, but I think it's impossible 99%.
- Create a folder in Hybris or Tomcat in which we can add our HTML files and the developers don't want to help us.

The only thing we need to do is to add landing pages to subdomain. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 100% possible in both ways.

1) You can use any reverse proxy/web server ([Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html), [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/), etc.) to redirect `/landings` request to the different server internally so that the end-user does not aware of this redirection. You can find a plethora of examples on the internet. If you are not aware of reverse proxy, refer [what is a reverse proxy?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)

2) You can design the same page using Hybris WCMS that can be opened with your desired URL `/landings`.

Comment: Could we create in Tomcat server a folder in which we will upload our HTML files and these files do not interfere with the Hybris application? @HybrisHelp

Comment: You can serve a static HTML file though same tomcat server. You have to decare docBase and path in the `server.xml`. Refer to [this article](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/) for more information